# Append parent table column value to child table column in sql

Tags: sql-server

Assume I have two tables, as below:

Table 1

```
ID           Name
------------------
1            Adam
2            Eve
```

Table 2

```
ID           FK_ID (Table 1)          Name
--------------------------------------------
1                   1                 Chris
2                   1                 Austin
3                   1                 Steve
4                   2                 Charles
5                   2                 Erik
6                   2                 Austin
```

Required table as Result

```
ID          Name
-----------------
1           Chris
2           Austin Adam
3           Steve
4           Charles
5           Erik
6           Austin Eve
```

Notice here, in the resulting table I want repeated "Austin" appended with "Adam/Eve" from parent table (i.e. Table 1), depending on "FK_ID". I want to do this in SQL. Any idea/help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a window count to determine whether a name is repeated or not:

```
SELECT t2.ID, 
       CONCAT(t2.Name,
          IIF(COUNT(t2.Name) OVER(PARTITION BY t2.Name) > 1, 
              COALESCE(' ' + t1.Name, ''), 
              ''))
FROM TABLE2 AS t2
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 AS t1 ON t2.FK_ID = t1.ID
```

Comment: great, if you just change `IIF` to `CASE` and use `+`, this would work on all SQL Server versions 2005 + (since the question isn't tagged with any specific version)

Comment: Coincidentally, basic idea is shared by all of the answers. But I appreciate the technique you have used to solve this. That's really good.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `GROUP BY Name` to check names with `count(*) > 1` and then do a `LEFT JOIN` to append `T1` names appropriately

**Sample Data**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([ID] int, [Name] varchar(4));

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([ID], [Name])
VALUES
    (1, 'Adam'),
    (2, 'Eve');

CREATE TABLE Table2
    ([ID] int, [FK_ID] int, [Name] varchar(7));

INSERT INTO Table2
    ([ID], [FK_ID], [Name])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'Chris'),
    (2, 1, 'Austin'),
    (3, 1, 'Steve'),
    (4, 2, 'Charles'),
    (5, 2, 'Erik'),
    (6, 2, 'Austin');
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    T2.ID,
    T2.Name + CASE WHEN T3.Name IS NOT NULL THEN ' ' + T1.Name ELSE '' END as Name
FROM Table2 T2
INNER JOIN Table1 T1 ON T2.[FK_ID] = T1.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Name FROM Table2 GROUP BY Name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) T3 ON T2.Name = T3.Name
```

**Output**

```
ID  Name
1   Chris
2   Austin Adam
3   Steve
4   Charles
5   Erik
6   Austin Eve
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT ID,NAME
    FROM TABLE2
    WHERE NAME NOT IN (
        SELECT NAME
        FROM TABLE2
        GROUP BY NAME
        HAVING COUNT(*) >1 )
    UNION
    SELECT A.ID AS ID,A.NAME+' '+B.NAME AS NAME
    FROM TABLE2 AS A INNER JOIN TABLE1 AS B
    ON A.FK_ID = B.ID
    WHERE NAME IN (
        SELECT NAME
        FROM TABLE2
        GROUP BY NAME
        HAVING COUNT(*) >1 )
   ORDER BY ID
```

Using union to process the logic by two group.